# Oracle SQL Trigger Help (sell item, change inventory)

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Trying to make a trigger that takes away (sells) an item from inventory.  When I enter:

```
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES (10, ‘C’, ‘Espresso’, 5, 10.00);
```

Here is my attempt at making a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_UPDATE_INVENTORY
AFTER INSERT ON ____ FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN   
UPDATE BB_PRODUCT   
SET STOCK = STOCK - :NEW._______
WHERE BB_PRODUCT.IDPRODUCT = :NEW.IDPRODUCT;
end;
```

Not sure what the put in the blanks.  Don't know if NEW.IDPRODUCT is correct either.

Here are some tables:

```
BB_PRODUCT (IDPRODUCT, PRODUCTNAME, DESCRIPTION, PRODUCT IMAGE, PRICE,       SALESTART, SALEEND, SALEPRICE, ACTIVE, FEATURED, FEATUREDSTART,  FEATUREDEND, TYPE, IDDEPARTMENT, STOCK, ORDERED, REORDER)

BB_Product_Request (IDREQUEST, IDPRODUCT, DTREQUEST, DTRECD, COST, QTY, IDVENDER)

BB_SALES_SUM (IDPRODUCT, TOT_SALES, TOT_QTY)

BB_PROD_SALES (IDPRODUCT, MONTH, YEAR, QTY, TOTAL)
```

Completely new to triggers, any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

***UPDATE***

Trigger works, thanks for the help.

Got the insert statement to work as well.  I put all the values in single quotations marks and it seems to be working.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I don't think asking for help on homework questions is allowed on this site without making some sort of attempt.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: `‘C’` and `‘Espresso’` is invalid. In SQL you use "straight" single quotes. It would need to be `'C'` and `'Espresso'`

Comment: @Mocking This is my attempt, none of the code was given to be in the homework question.  I left blanks on the tables I was not sure of.  But I really appreciate the help, thanks.  Still trying to figure out the correct INSERT statement though.  I read the tutorials and it seems simple enough, but just isn't working for me.

Comment: Edit your question to include insert attempts.  That way you can show you at least tried and we can help you fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the documentation for an insert statement.  Your insert statement is written incorrectly: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm

Or a 'beginner' friendly tutorial:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php

You need to specify a table and columns (if you aren't inserting a value for every column) to insert the values into.

The following is the answer to the blanks:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_UPDATE_INVENTORY
AFTER INSERT ON BB_PRODUCT_REQUEST FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN   
UPDATE BB_PRODUCT   
SET STOCK = STOCK - :NEW.QTY
WHERE BB_PRODUCT.IDPRODUCT = :NEW.IDPRODUCT;
end;
```

You are inserting a request for a product (thus a trigger on BB_PRODUCT_REQUEST) and subtracting the request qty from the available stock in the BB_PRODUCT table.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't really read it but the syntax was the same so I made an assumption.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

What you're not showing is the table definition for `LINE`. If you want the trigger fired following an `INSERT INTO LINE ...` then the trigger needs to be on the `LINE` table.

So `ON ____` would be replaced by `ON LINE`, since `LINE` is the name of the table.

Presumably, one of the columns in the `LINE` table is a foreign key referencing `BB_PRODUCT.IDPRODUCT`.  We aren't given any indication as to the name of that column in the `LINE` table.  `:NEW.foo` is the correct way to reference the value of the `foo` column on the row that was just inserted into `LINE`. If that column is named `IDPRODUCT` in the `LINE` table, then what you have looks right.

As far as what value you want to subtract from `STOCK`, again, that depends on the name of the column in the `LINE` table.

---

If you wrote your insert statement to give the names of the columns you are inserting to, that would provide the information a reader would need (without having to go lookup the definition of the `LINE` table), and would also prevent the INSERT statement from breaking if someone adds a column to the table.

We're just guessing at the names of the columns:

```
INSERT INTO LINE (IDORDER, IDPRODUCT, ITEMDESC, QTY, UNITCOST)
VALUES (10, 'C', 'Espresso', 5, 10.00);
```

If that `5` in that row is what you want to subtract, from the row in `BB_PRODUCT`  where `IDPRODUCT = 'C'`...

Then:

```
  SET STOCK = STOCK - :NEW.QTY
```

---

Also, beware of `NULL` values. If `QTY` allows NULL values, and the row being inserted has a NULL value for `QTY`, then the expression `STOCK - :NEW.QTY` (in the SET clause of the UPDATE statement in the trigger) will evaluate to `NULl`, which will be assigned to `STOCK`. If there's a NOT NULL constraint on the `QTY` column, then we avoid the issue. (The NOT NULL constraint would throw an exception, and the trigger wouldn't be fired.)